# Problems with TableSorter Initial Number of Visible Rows

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I discovered **TableSorter** yesterday so it's obvious I don't understand much of it yet but, using several demos and reading the docs, I could setup a working sorting in a table until I discovered the **Pager Widget**.

It's not that it's not working, it's just not working as I would expect it to work. Most of my implementation is based on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/e3V9V/) provided by the author.

I just removed the **widthFixed** option and the zebra widget (because I didn't see it in action) and defined two of my four columns to not be sortable. I also modified slightly the output text of pager widget:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( 'table' ).tablesorter({

        theme: 'bootstrap',
        headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}',
        widgets: [ "uitheme" ],
        headers: {
            3:{sorter: false},
            4:{sorter: false}
        }
    }).tablesorterPager({

        container: $(".ts-pager"),
        saveSort : false,
        output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})'
    });

});
```

This script goes in the end of HTML, near the `</body>`, as an external file. Different of most usages of jQuery plugins, because I'm using one footer file common to all pages (part of server side programming), instead of add the scripts also in the end, I've added them right after the table to be sorted, in the following order:

```
<script src="/public/assets/projectfolder/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/assets/projectfolder/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/assets/projectfolder/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js"></script>
```

Now, the things I think that aren't working, but it's probably dumbness of my part, are.

- **Pager options being memorized after refresh**

I thought this was a bug until find the option saveSort and set it to false in tableSortPager options. However this didn't work as I would expect and what I chose in the page size dropdown was being kept after refresh just like if that option hasn't been set.

- **Initial number of visible rows doesn't work everytime**

The first time I've added the Pager widget, it worked. But because the default memory behavior is to remember the the sorting choices, every new request after that didn't work anymore. The initial number of visible rows is always the one picked in the page size dropdown.

This is so true that if I pick another value, the number changes as expected and, after a  refresh, the amount I picked before is the one displayed.

Reading the docs I saw the **size** option. I defined it with a low number (because I'm still building the GUI and I don't have real data) but, again, the number of rows displayed was the one memorized.

Cleaning browser cache makes this property work as intended, until a new value for page size is picked and, even with **saveSort** defined as **false**, be memorized again.

How could I solve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you want to use is the [pager `savePages` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#save-pages).

```
$(function(){
    $( 'table' ).tablesorter({
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}',
        widgets: [ "uitheme" ],
        headers: {
            3:{sorter: false},
            4:{sorter: false}
        }
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".ts-pager"),
        savePages : false,
        output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})'
    });
});
```

The [`saveSort` widget option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#widget-savesort) actually works with the saveSort widget, and that option belongs inside the widgetOptions:

```
$(function(){
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: ["saveSort"],
    widgetOptions : {
      // if false, the sort will not be saved for next page reload
      saveSort : false
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mottie, for savePages : false option, it is what I am looking for when I set the below and found it is not working. (taken from http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html)                                     // Number of visible rows - default is 10
    size: 10,

Comment: @AKS It's working fine for me, can you modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/4167/) to duplicate the issue.

Comment: @Mottie, Sorry for being not so clear. I read your article in github and It was my assumption that I only requires option size:6 as per my requirement but that is not working. After reading your answer here (above), i ADDED the option savePages : false after which the size:6 started working. I am not sure what savePages is related with showing number of lines in a table. The explanation of savePages gives me impression that some kind of saving (I am displaying only ) maybe for session etc if required needs this option. What savePages:true or providing no option for savePages do?

Comment: @AKS the reason it didn't appear to work is because the user set `savePages` size stored in local storage overrides the `size` option setting. You can update the stored value by either setting the page size using the `pageSize` selector or clearing the stored value using this code: `$.tablesorter.storage( $('table'), 'tablesorter-pager', '' );` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/4173/))

Comment: Thank you very much Mottie, the key I missed is "savePages size stored in local storage overrides the size option setting". Now I understand it.

Comment: Lots of problems with the plugin just dumbed it...looking for some other option